# Replacing first occurence in every line

Tags: shell, scripting, sed

Supposing I have a document formatted like this:

```
word1 word2 word3
word4 word5 word6
word7 word8
```

How do I use `sed` to replace the first occurence of space with a comma followed by a space so that the document will look like:

```
word1, word2 word3
word4, word5 word6
word7, word8
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo word1 word2 word3|sed -r 's/(\s)/,\1/'
```

output:

```
word1, word2 word3
```

Comment: what about line with at only space

Comment: if you have such lines, place `/^\s+$/!` on top.

Answer (score 6):

Simple:

```
sed -i 's/ /, /' your_file
```

This looks for the first occurrence of a space, replaces it with a comma and space, then moves to the next line.

Answer (score 2):

how about:

```
sed -e 's/\s\+/, /'
```

output:

```
word1, word2 word3
word4, word5 word6
word7, word8
```

Comment: This would replace one or more spaces with a , followed by a space.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`

```
awk '{sub(/ /,", ")}1' file
word1, word2 word3
word4, word5 word6
word7, word8
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It isn't regex-dependent yet effective!

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/\([^[:blank:]]\{1,\}\)/\1,/' YourFile
```

Add a `,` after first block of "non space", so start of line could be starting with space, it still work and also if line is without work but only with space (no `,` in this case)

Answer (score 1):

echo FRIEND TOO MUCH |sed 's/ /, /'

FRIEND, TOO MUCH